How does force vector affect rotation and translation?
I have a simple question (I think).
There is an object e.g. a circle. We apply an impulse force F. No other forces are applied.
Situation 1. Two force vectors, on the opposite sides of the object. The are both perpendicular to the center of mass (to the radius from the center to the edge). Both of them have the same value, direction and sense. Therefore there will only translation, parallel to the direction of vectors.
Situation 2. Similar, but one of the vectors is flipped (has opposite sense). Therefore there will be only rotation.
But what will happen in situation 3 and 4?
Situation 3. There is only one vector, placed on the edge of the object, perpendicular to the center. Will it result only in rotation (that's what they taught me at school years ago)? But if that's the case, why did situation 1 result in translation?
Situation 4. Similar to situation 3, but now the force vector is at the angle outwards. Will it result in rotation and translation to the side or up? And finally, is it possible to determine velocity and angular velocity of the object based on the theta (angle of force vector), force value, object mass and radius?
For me situation 1 cancels out rotations and situation 2 cancels out translations, but I'm unable to support it with calculations.
Thank you in advance for any ideas, answers, sources. I've only found videos and texts about translation and rotation separately or cylinder on a ramp (but there gravity causes translation and rotation via friction, so it's a different scenario than one here).

Other link for image, if above doesn't work:
https://postimg.cc/mP3X89m7

Situation 3 can be decomposed into Situation 1 and Situation 2 and so you should be able to understand what happens next. Situation 4 can be decomposed into Situation 3 and one other force, similar to Situation 1, and so that also can be solved.

@naturallyInconsistent Although combining 1 and 2 results in both translation and rotation as in 3, would you agree that 1+2 is not equivalent to 3 (as it would result in a force of 2F for situation 3)?

@naturallyInconsistent I... don't understand. How exactly does the decomposition go? Do you mean I have to merge situation 1 and 2, thus getting both rotation and translation? And that the force applied is divided by 2 (one half goes to rotation and the other to translation)? If that's the case, then situation 4 is, indeed, easy to solve using situation 3.

@Eight If you superimpose 1 and 2 the forces on the left cancel and the forces one the right add, providing both angular and linear acceleration.

This is what you obtain, if you transfer the forces to the center of mass.
Why ?
For the center of mass you obtain two equations
$$ m~a= \sum F$$
$$ I~\alpha=\sum \tau $$
You obtain the same results for the un–transfer  forces and for the transfer forces.


So I always transfer force to the center, when I calculate translation? And no matter where the force vector was placed, it always affects translation the same? So there is no "this force causes both translation and a little rotation, so 80% of the value goes to the translation and 20% to rotation"?

The first part is correct, but why „80% of the value goes to the translation and 20% to rotation“ ?

Example of this idea, based on force vs mass. If I use force F to push a cart with 1 box, it's going to speed up by some value. However if I put 2 boxes, it's going to be accelerated less. Obvious, because a = F/m. So similarly accelerating just translation is less work than accelerating translation + rotation. It just looks counter-intutitive looking at energy, if you say E=transl. kinetic is the same as E=transl. kinetic + rot. kinetic rotation, where translational kinetic is equal in both scenarios.

In other words:
Force is placed on the object's center of mass: E = mv^2 / 2.
Same force is placed on the object's edge: E = mv^2 / 2 + Iw^2 / 2.
So either the force produces more/less energy based on its placement or some of the v velocity was converted into w velocity.
I'm probably wrong, but I don't know the reason, why.

lets take case 3. the equations of motion at the center of mass are always
$~m a=F~,I,\alpha=F,r~$ , hence is energy is $~2,E=m,v^2+I,\omega^2~$ where $v=\int a,dt~$ and $~\omega=\int \alpha,dt$

So since $a = \frac{F}{m}$, the linear velocity 'v' won't ever change. So in case 3, if I move the force vector to the center of mass instead, the total energy will be smaller than in original case 3? Therefore the work is different based on the placement of the force vector?


Situation 3. There is only one vector, placed on the edge of the
object, perpendicular to the center. Will it result only in rotation

No. It will result in rotation plus translation since there is a net force as well as a net torque acting on the object.

Situation 4. Similar to situation 3, but now the force vector is at
the angle outwards. Will it result in rotation and translation to the
side or up?

It will result in translation and rotation just like situation 3. But the angular acceleration will be less in situation 4 since the component of the force causing the torque is less.

And finally, is it possible to determine velocity and angular velocity
of the object based on the theta (angle of force vector), force value,
object mass and radius?

Yes, but you would need the duration of the impulse.

For me situation 1 cancels out rotations and situation 2 cancels out
translations, but I'm unable to support it with calculations.

Angular acceleration requires a net torque, which is zero for situation 1. Linear acceleration requires a net force, which is zero for situation 2.
Hope this helps.

Situation 3: there is a net vertical force, so there will be vertical motion.  And there is a net torque about the center of mass, so there also will be rotation.  That's why it's a combination of (1) and (2).  The net acceleration will be half of that in (1) and the net angular acceleration will be half of that in (2).
You either remembered the answer incorrectly from school, or they gave you the wrong answer, or the problem included a central hinge point that wasn't clearly specified (assuming there is no hinge for these examples).
Situation 4 will be like 3 except the motion will be at an angle, in the direction of the force.  And the angular acceleration is slightly lower, unless the force is tangent.

Thank you! No hinge. Just a single object in space. Also, I remembered correctly. I talked to friends, who now have the same teacher and they were told the same rule - force going through the center is translation only and when we rotate the force outwards it becomes more and more "focused" on rotation, until we reach the situation 3, where it's rotation only.

Your teacher is right that a  single force through the center produces no rotation.  And they are right that the farther out that force is applied, the higher the torque and therefore the greater effect on rotation.  But they are wrong that it becomes rotation-only.  An unbalanced force must always produce motion.  F = ma.
